# PHP member data lost when abstract method returns

Tags: php, class, abstract

Here's an example of an abstract class and a derived class.  There is one abstract method, "collectData" in class A, that is implemented in class B.  When the method "getData" is called, "collectData" is then called, setting values in the private member variable "$data".  Afterward, getData returns the contents of this variable.  If you run this, you would expect the return value to be array(1, 2, 3).  But it is an empty array.  Why?  I'm using PHP 5.3.10 by the way.

```
<?php

abstract class A
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array();  
    }

    abstract protected function collectData();

    public function getData()
    {
        $this->collectData();
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected function collectData()
    {
        $this->data = array(1, 2, 3);
    }
}

$test = new B();
$data = $test->getData();
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not be:

```
private $data;
```

but:

```
protected $data;
```

Private properties are not visible after derivation.

Comment: Darn, such a simple oversight.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `$data` property `public` or `protected` and You will see...

If the property is private, `print_r` does not see it... Or call `var_dump($data)` - this should print out also the private members...

Answer (score 0):

Put a setter and a getter in your abstract class to manage the data property

```
public function setData($data){
   $this->data = $data;
}

public function getData($data){
   return $this->data;
}
```